# Problem validating form using AJAX jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I want to validate a login form using AJAX but i can't get it works. The problem is on the "success" part i think.
(I'm ussing Codeigniter framework)
Here's my code:

controller:

```
function verificarSesion()
{
    if($this->input->post("submitLogin"))
    {
        $var = $this->usuariosModelo->verificarSesion();
        if($var)
        {
            $sesion = array("usuario" => $this->input->post("usuario"));
            $this->session->set_userdata($sesion);
            echo "0";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "1";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "2";
    }
}
```

model:

```
function verificarSesion()
{
    $consulta = $this->db->get_where("usuarios", array(
                                    "usuario"=>$this->input->post("usuario", TRUE),
                                    "contraseña"=>$this->input->post("contraseña", TRUE)));
    if($consulta->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

view:

```
<form name="formIni" id="formIni2" action="<?php echo base_url('verifSesion');?>" method="POST" >
<label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
<input type="text" name="usuario">

<label for="contraseña">Contraseña</label>
<input type="password" name="contraseña">

<input onclick="funcion()" type="submit" value="Login" name="submitLogin">
```

and the script:

```
function funcion()
{
    $("#formIni2").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({ //envio por ajax los datas
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            type: $(this).attr("method"),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success:function(resp){
                if(resp!=0)
                {
                    alert("not ok");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("ok");
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Without the AJAX request everything works fine, that's why i think the error is in the script.
What I could observe is that the var `resp` isn't getting the value.

Thanks.

Edit 1: 
[I can see the "0" from the echo but also two more characters that i don't know where they came from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEgpR.png)

Edit 2:
I edited the controller function "verificarSesion()", the returns now are "0", "1" and "2", and i'm seeing that always return "2".

Comment: i don't know the language your working with, but would assume it would be more so like this - if resp.val instead of just resp.

Comment: You are creating a trigger upon clicking but not triggering it. Remove the $("#formIni2").submit block

Comment: If i remove that it just act like a normal form submit.

Comment: Try To `echo "0";` as a string and in success callback function use `var resp = resp.trim();` before the `if` statemenet .. Also use `resp !== "0"` as string not number

Comment: I got rid of those characters with trim, now i'm seeing that "resp" is always getting 0, but if i try using the form without that script the echo shows 1.

Comment: In Ajax request use -    method: $(this).attr("method"),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
function verificarSesion()
{
    if ($this->input->method(TRUE) == "POST")
    {
        $var = $this->usuariosModelo->verificarSesion();
        if($var)
        {
            $sesion = array("usuario" => $this->input->post("usuario"));
            $this->session->set_userdata($sesion); //asigna una sesion
            echo "1";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "2";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "3";
    }
}
```

I just have to change

> if($this->input->post("submitLogin"))

for

> if ($this->input->method(TRUE) == "POST")

On the controller function.

And the script now is:

```
function funcion()
{
    $("#formIni2").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            type: $(this).attr("method"),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success:function(resp){
                alert(resp.trim());
                if(resp.trim()==="1")
                {
                    window.location.href = "http://localhost/principal"
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Los datos son incorrectos.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks everyone :).